# How to perform a correlation test in a loop, while removing a row from the dataframe in every iteration?

Tags: r, for-loop, sapply, pearson-correlation

I am trying to remove a row from my dataframe in every iteration in a for loop and perform correlation test on the newly saved dataframe. However, I am not getting what I expect. Please help. Each row in the dataframe provided represents corresponding column name data of an individual.

```
rnpo <- data.frame(h.move.ten = c(25.85, 51.375, 26.007, 35.249, 30.841), move.ten = c(3.231, 0.000, 4.334, 4.745, 0.000), reor.ten = c(0.000, 3.626, 1.181, 2.027, 2.457), hbob.ten = c(3.398, 17.934, 7.050, 1.075, 0.943))

store.cor <- numeric(nrow(rnpo))

for (i in 1:nrow(rnpo)) {
  droprow <- rnpo[-i,]
  store.cor[i] <- cor(droprow)
}
```

This is the code that I am trying to use.

Alternatively, I am trying to use:

```
store.cor <- numeric(nrow(rnpo))
data.ind <- 1:nrow(rnpo) 
store.cor <- sapply(data.ind, function(x) cor(rnpo[-x]))
calc.cor <- function(x,vec) {
  cor(vec[-x])
}
store.cor <- sapply(data.ind, calc.cor, vec=rnpo)
store.cor
```

Here, my columns are getting dropped in every iteration instead of my rows. How to fix this problem?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. How many columns does `rnpo` have?

Comment: Hi @MrFlick I have updated my questions with 4 columns and 5 rows of rnpo. Please let me know what can be done.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't provided a sample dataset, here is a generic solution that you can adapt to your needs. This approach creates a copy of your dataset to iteratively remove rows from, and an empty list to store results:

```
# set.seed() only needed for making a reproducible example df, 
# you won't need it for your full dataset
set.seed(1)

# Create example dataframe
rnpo <- data.frame(a = 1:20,
                   b = sample(1:20, 20))

# Create copy of your data to remove rows from
droprow <- rnpo
# Create empty list to store results 
store.cor <- list()

# Use while() to iterate over "droprow" and perform cor()
while(nrow(droprow) > 1) {
  
  store.cor <- rbind(store.cor, cor(droprow))
  droprow <- droprow[-1,]
  
}

head(store.cor)
  a         b        
a 1         0.3383459
b 0.3383459 1        
a 1         0.2690311
b 0.2690311 1        
a 1         0.2281195
b 0.2281195 1
```

Note: I placed the code that drops the rows last in the `while()` loop so that `cor()` is run on the full dataset as well. You can switch the order if this is incorrect. Further, the `rownames()` in "store.cor" have a numeric value appended so you can identify each calculation. These numbers do not show when using `head()`.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for your reply. I have updated the code with a dataframe. Please let me know what can be done with it. Each row in the dataframe provided represents corresponding column name data of an individual.